# how can I use multiple methods in a route?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to understand how to associate more methods to my route. For example:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DController@showX')->middleware('auth');
```

Besides `showX()` I have another function called `showY()` that I would like to associate with the route, but if I rewrite it twice it doesn't go, how can I solve the problem?

Controller:

```php
public function showY(){
    $name=Auth::user()->name;
    return view('dashboard',['name'=>$name]);
}

public function showX(){
    $y= Y::all();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it from the route like that. How would you handle two return values?

Judging by the controller methods, maybe you want to use the value of `showX` in `showY`?

The way I see to handle this would be to have one method in the route:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DController@show')->middleware('auth');
```

and have it fire both of your other methods:

```php
public function show() {
    // decide what to return
    $xValue = $this->showX();
    return $this->showY($xValue);
}

protected function showY($y){
    $name=Auth::user()->name;
    return view('dashboard',['name' => $name, 'y' => $y]);
}

protected function showX(){
    $y= Y::all();
}
```

Comment: No I don't want this, I practically have a view in which I use a datatable is through the `showX()` function I print the values, and through `showY()` I print a variable inside the same view, since if I use 

    Route :: get ('/ dashboard', 'DController @ showX')> middleware ( 'auth');`

I can't even use 

`Route :: get ('/ dashboard', 'DController @ showY')> middleware ('auth'); `

because one works is the other no I would like to know how to use a single instruction to recall both methods within the same view without where to combine the two methods in a method inside the controller

Comment: This can't be done the way you describe, and doesn't make sense from a fundamental level. Your chain can't diverge and then magically re-merge to add values. If one function is to add values to the other, one needs to be called by the other or both called from a parent function with the value passed in as an argument. Maybe do some research on [blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade) and see if including some PHP there will accomplish what you need.